# Dynamic php mysqli SQL statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, dynamic, dynamic-programming

Using mysqli prepared statement to prevent SQL injection, how to dynamically bind SQL statement?

There a few combinations of the SQL that concerned: If user select one or more items, the SQL string will use **IN** clause, if user did not select any item (empty), the SQL string will use **LIKE** clause:

**Condition 1**

```
select category,uom,product 
from tbl_product 
where category like '%'
and uom like '%'
and product like '%'
```

**Condition 2**

```
select category,uom,product 
from tbl_product 
where category in ('Soft Drinks','Liquor')
and uom in ('Can','Bottle')
and product in ('Pepsi','Coca Cola','Budweiser')
```

**Condition 3**

```
select category,uom,product 
from tbl_product 
where category in ('Soft Drinks','Liquor')
and uom in ('Can','Bottle')
and product like '%'
```

**PHP Code**

For single value I am using below code

```
$sql_product = $conn->prepare("select * from tbl_product where category = ?");
$sql_product->bind_param('s', $category);
$sql_product->execute();
```

Comment: My requirements are different, have a look at *Condition 3* where the uom and product could be in and like respectively.

Comment: Matching via `LIKE` and `IN` are simply different, so you need different queries for that. What is the "dynamically" you want there?